# Make jquery script 1.5.2 compatible with when function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I need to make this function

```
$.when(
    self.image.fadeOut(self.options.animationSpeed),
    self.aniImg.eq(0).fadeIn(self.options.animationSpeed)
).done(function () {
    self.finishAnimating(data);
});
```

into a function that is compatible with jquery 1.5.

I have been trying, but can't get it to work. can anyone help me please ?

@Edit: I did a setup here http://jsfiddle.net/u4hWf/. As you can see, with jquery 1.5.2 strange visual things happen, which don't with jquery 1.6.x If someone could take a look that would be awesome

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want that `done` function to execute when the `fadeOut` and the `fadeIn` have both occurred?

Comment: Well, I am not that much off a jquery expert, but this is a peace of code that works with jquery 1.6. I can't exactly tell you what it does (please tell me). But this should be transformed to jquery 1.5 (in which I didn't succeed) with a deffered object.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `$.when` call is entirely useless, even in 1.6, since nothing happens when it is complete.

Comment: Can you: tell me in human language what the code says, do you have any idea how to put it like a deffered object? http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ you would help me out alot

Comment: OK, sorry, I misread the code, due to the odd indentation. I've fixed my own attempt to format it sensibly, and it makes sense now. I'll post an answer...

Comment: Any particular reason you need to go backwards in jQuery version #?

Comment: The methods `when` and `done` are supported in jQuery 1.5. So what you have should work unless there is a bug in jQuery. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @mrtsherman is right: this should work in jQuery 1.5, though I have now posted an even-more-backwards compatible version...

Comment: Yes, I see now, I was working with an even older version of jquery. I can't pdate higher than 1.5 because of compatibility. 1.5 does work but gives strange behaviour compared to 1.6+. Can you please check out the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't going to make anything as beautiful as the code with the Deferred style. I'd strongly urge you to look at upgrading the version of jQuery.

This code simply runs one bit of code once two asynchronous bits of code are complete. Given that they have the same duration given, you could simply delay the code by that amount of time:

```
self.image.fadeOut(self.options.animationSpeed);
self.aniImg.eq(0).fadeIn(self.options.animationSpeed);
setTimeout(function() {
    self.finishAnimating(data);
}, self.options.animationSpeed);
```

This is the quick and (slightly) hackish approach.  Another would be to run a function that only executes a bit of code when the correct number of functions have completed.

```
var ticks = 0;

function tick() {
    if (++ticks === 2) { // number of animations
        self.finishAnimating(data);
    }
}

self.image.fadeOut(self.options.animationSpeed, tick);
self.aniImg.eq(0).fadeIn(self.options.animationSpeed, tick);
```

This is more verbose, and again not very pretty, but it more precisely replicates the `$.when` behaviour, and is more extensible.